# Lottie animations with images

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

A basic question (I'm new to Lottie):
I have a JSON animation file which supposes to work with images.
If I see this (for example) at the JSON:
{"ty":4,"nm":"txt-notice","ip":0,"st": ....

So I need to have an image named txt-notice ?
And if so, can I add it to some .xcassets folder?